# listen to event emitted by component from a programatic route in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component which emits events that I can listen successfully to:

```
<email-widget 
    v-bind:company-id="clicked_company_id" 
    v-bind:project-id="clicked_project_id"
    v-on:project-clicked="onClickProjectId"
>
</email-widget>
```

I am now updating my system to use routers, and I have a programmatic router that looks like this:

```
let emailComponent= Vue.component('email-widget')

const routes = [
    { path: '/settings', component: Bar },
    { 
        path: '/emails', 
        name: 'emails',
        component: emailComponent 
    },

]

router.push({ name: 'emails', 
    params: {}
})
```

This renders correctly.

But how do I add a listener for the event?

Updates:

This solution works:

```
<router-view
  :company-id="clicked_company_id" 
  :project-id="clicked_project_id"
  @project-clicked="onClickProjectId">
</router-view>
```

However, the whole point of the router-view is to switch which component is inside it. If the second component emits `project-clicked` as well, but I want to handle it differently, how would I do that?

Basically, I want to bind the listener to a component instance which I created earlier as `emailComponent`, **not** to the `router-view`.

Comment: Since you need to handle the events in distinct manner, why can't you put them inside the individual components?

Comment: Because the event type triggers a state change on other independent components on the same screen. Basically you click different things in an email, and it displays information elsewhere. But it can display something other than an email, and that component could emit the same event string but the other component should behave differently.

Comment: OK, got your point. But sorry I still can't wrap my head around why these handlers can't go inside the components themselves.

Comment: If the handler went inside the component, wouldn't it bind all the components together very tightly? For me the whole promise of components is the loose binding: they shouldn't have to know what is driving their state, and should just respond reactivly.

Comment: "Respond reactively" -- that's it, without a prior knowledge or a reference to anything to react to (like in-component `props` or parent component data), how can a view decide on what to even use/call in the template or methods? Unless I'm missing something. But there might be a workaround for your use case.

Comment: Maybe some component structure can help us see the bigger picture here. ATM, I'm picturing a view containing multiple, independent components that rely on the same information passed down to by the parent, and these components need to somehow be aware of the same event emitted by the calling component.

Comment: Or, you could be trying to broadcast something to all independent components within the same template, which shouldn't be an issue if they simply listen to the event(s). I think this is too broad and need more structural details. If you can unaccept my offered solution, until I (or someone else) can get you the one you are likely to be happy about, please feel free to do so. My current solution of course does cover the common needs for *global* event emission and/or props binding.

Comment: Perhaps the smaller view of the problem is better: how do I bind an event listener to a specific instance of a component? If the router-view can contain two different components (C1 and C2) , and both emit "event-X" how do I distinguish between C1.event-X and C2.event-X (without writing code in the event handler to check what is currently displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply attach them on the `<router-view>`, because it is just a component.

```
<router-view
  :company-id="clicked_company_id" 
  :project-id="clicked_project_id"
  @project-clicked="onClickProjectId">
</router-view>
```

Comment: This seems correct. The reason I didn't think of it is that I switch the component out and put a new one in which doesn't emit that event. 


What do I do then? I guess there is no harm having the listener attached, but what if another component emitted that same event name?

Comment: Well, if that other component is directly nested inside the same `router-view`, the same event(s) should bubble up and trigger and listener(s). Let us know what you are trying to achieve specifically though.

Comment: I'm switching between two components. If they both emit an event of the same name my listener would trigger for both. I really want to bind the listener to a specific instance of one of the components, not the container that either of them could be in.

Comment: The listener should really only react to the triggering component.

Comment: Exactly.. So how do I wire that up? The router-view wiring mechanism only accepts an event name string.

Comment: Can you update your question and include some example input-output?

Comment: Question updated with extra details. Thanks for your help @Yom S.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should do that. Instead you should pass the function `onClickProjectId` as a prop, and instead of emitting the event, you should call that function.

```
:onClick = "onClickProjectId"
```

This way you would have more control of what that component is doing inside the component itself.

Otherwise you can go ahead with what Yom S has suggested above.

Comment: This seems like an argument against events completely, which doesn't seem right. What am I missing?